# \pgfmathsetmacro isn't setting the macro

Tags: pgfplots

Cheers everyone.

I have "thee old" `\pgfmathsetmacro` problem and can't for the life of
me not solve it. Is there a glitch between TikZ and PGFPlots that
escapes me. I just want to draw the lines between x-values and
y-values in the `\foreach` loop at the bottom but have gotten all
sorts of errors during the day. The most recent and pertaining to this
version of my trials and errors is "Undefined control sequence" on the
`\result` macro. The error is at the line of `\draw` command

Anyone catches the error?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=latex,
        font={\footnotesize},
        declare function={
          f(\x) = .5 + \x - sin(\x*180/3.14;
        }
  ]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
    axis lines = middle,
    domain = 0.5:3,
    clip = false
  ]
  \addplot[black!70, very thick]{f(x)};
  \foreach \i in {0.25, 2.25}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{f(\i)};
    \draw (0, \result) -- (\i, result) -- (\i, 0);
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that the `axis` environment stores up its drawing commands until the end of the environment and then executes them all at once.  It gathers them up without expansion, meaning that your `\draw` commands get saved as you've written them.  However, outside the `\foreach` loop then the `\result` macro isn't defined, hence the error (note that the error is actually reported at the `\end{axis}` line, not the `\draw` line).  There are a few ways to get round this, but the simplest in your case is to force the the macros that you want expanded to be expanded at invocation time.  A fairly standard way to do this is to define an auxiliary macro to be the `\draw` command with the expanded coordinates and then invoke that.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325334/86}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=latex,
        font={\footnotesize},
        declare function={
          f(\x) = .5 + \x - sin(\x*180/3.14;
        }
  ]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    width=10cm,
    height=10cm,
    axis lines = middle,
    domain = 0.5:3,
    clip = false
  ]
  \addplot[black!70, very thick]{f(x)};
  \foreach \i in {0.25, 2.25}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{f(\i)}
  \edef\temp{
    \noexpand\draw (0, \result) -- (\i, \result) -- (\i, 0);
  }
  \temp
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Note that because your axes run from `(0.5,0.5)` the boxes look a bit out of place, but that's a feature of the choice of origin not anything to do with TeX.

Comment: Sweet. You SE gurus are great. I've seen the work around before. I didn't get that it applied to me. I just added my `xmin=0, ymin=0` and the boxes fitted nicely. Thanks a lot. Cheers.