# problems with foreach loop and intersections

Tags: foreach, intersections

I have a problem using `foreach loop` and `intersection`.

My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\height{10cm}
    \def\width{10cm}
    \def\sc{0.8}
    
    \def\xmin{0}
    \def\xmax{5}
    \def\ymin{0}
    \def\ymax{40000}    
    \def\enlarge{0.05}
    
    \def\Gda{12244}
    \def\Gdb{4773.48}
    \def\Gdc{1861}      % Gdb/Gda*Gdb   
    \def\Gpa{15526.95}
    \def\Gpb{6053.38}   % Gdb/Gda*Gpb
    \def\aa{1.87}
    \def\ab{1.76}
    \def\ac{1.66}       % ab/aa*ab
    \def\reqa{2.67}
    \def\reqb{2.97}
    \def\reqc{3.30}     % reqb/reqa*reqb
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            height=\height, 
            width=\width, 
            scale only axis=true, 
            scale=\sc, 
            enlarge x limits=\enlarge, 
            enlarge y limits=\enlarge,
            samples=500,
            domain=\xmin:\xmax,
            restrict y to domain=\ymin:\ymax,
            xlabel=$\mathrm{R}$,
            ylabel=$\mathrm{E(R)}$,
            ]
            
            \addplot[
            name path global=A,
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\Gda*(1-exp(-\aa*(x-\reqa)))^2});
            
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\Gpa+\Gdb*(1-exp(-\ab*(x-\reqb)))^2});
            
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\Gpa+\Gpb+\Gdc*(1-exp(-\ac*(x-\reqc)))^2});

        \foreach [evaluate=\i as \n using 216.92*(\i + 0.5) - 2.07*(\i + 0.5)^2] \i in {0,4,...,20} {%
            \edef\temp{\noexpand%
%               \path[name path global=B] (axis cs:\xmin,\n) -- (axis cs:\xmax,\n); % <- here is my problem
%               \path[name intersections={of=A and B},];
%               \coordinate (A1)  at (intersection-1);
%               \coordinate (B1)  at (intersection-2);
%               \draw[line width=0.5pt] (A1) -- (B1);
                \draw (axis cs:\xmin,\n) -- (axis cs:\xmax,\n);
            }\temp
        }

        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to compute in the foreach loop the y value and draw a horizontal line in-between the plotted potential. My guess is, that there is a problem with the name of the coordinates and the paths, since I can draw the lines without errors, but unfortunately I could not find a solution.

The current plot looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amusingly enough, when I copied your code to save as a TeX document to play around with then I tried to save it as `pgfplotsforeach.tex` only to discover that I already have a file with that name as the answer to [\pgfmathsetmacro isn't setting the macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325334/86).  I'm guessing that you have also seen that question because you have the `\edef\temp{...}\temp` in your `\foreach` which looks very like it came from that answer.

The issue is actually the same as in that answer: since `pgfplots` saves up commands until the end of the `axis` environment, you have to think very carefully about what will be known at that time.  Expanding macros is only part of it, you also have to think about coordinate and path names.  Fortunately, in a foreach loop then there is an easy way to make things unique - simply append the loop counter to the name (with one caveat: if looping over decimals then one should use the `count` key on the loop to get an integer and append that since coordinate names with periods in them are not a good idea).

You also need to `\noexpand` all the path construction commands inside your `\edef`, not just the first.

So here's a working version of your code (I think!):

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/586094/86}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\height{10cm}
    \def\width{10cm}
    \def\sc{0.8}
    
    \def\xmin{0}
    \def\xmax{5}
    \def\ymin{0}
    \def\ymax{40000}    
    \def\enlarge{0.05}
    
    \def\Gda{12244}
    \def\Gdb{4773.48}
    \def\Gdc{1861}      % Gdb/Gda*Gdb   
    \def\Gpa{15526.95}
    \def\Gpb{6053.38}   % Gdb/Gda*Gpb
    \def\aa{1.87}
    \def\ab{1.76}
    \def\ac{1.66}       % ab/aa*ab
    \def\reqa{2.67}
    \def\reqb{2.97}
    \def\reqc{3.30}     % reqb/reqa*reqb
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[
            height=\height, 
            width=\width, 
            scale only axis=true, 
            scale=\sc, 
            enlarge x limits=\enlarge, 
            enlarge y limits=\enlarge,
            samples=500,
            domain=\xmin:\xmax,
            restrict y to domain=\ymin:\ymax,
            xlabel=$\mathrm{R}$,
            ylabel=$\mathrm{E(R)}$,
            ]
            
            \addplot[
            name path global=A,
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\Gda*(1-exp(-\aa*(x-\reqa)))^2});
            
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\Gpa+\Gdb*(1-exp(-\ab*(x-\reqb)))^2});
            
            \addplot[
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\Gpa+\Gpb+\Gdc*(1-exp(-\ac*(x-\reqc)))^2});

        \foreach [evaluate=\i as \n using 216.92*(\i + 0.5) - 2.07*(\i + 0.5)^2] \i in {0,4,...,20} {%
            \edef\temp{\noexpand%
               \path[name path global=B-\i] (axis cs:\xmin,\n) -- (axis cs:\xmax,\n); % <- here is my problem
    \noexpand\path[name intersections={of=A and B-\i},];
    \noexpand\coordinate (A1-\i)  at (intersection-1);
    \noexpand\coordinate (B1-\i)  at (intersection-2);
    \noexpand\draw (axis cs:\xmin,\n) -- (axis cs:\xmax,\n);
    \noexpand\draw[red,line width=0.5pt] (A1-\i) -- (B1-\i);
  }\temp
        }

        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've zoomed in on the relevant part, and coloured the lines in red to make them obvious.

[image: Marking points between curves]

Comment: @ Andrew Stacey thanks a lot for the fast answer. Actually, I don't know about your related answer and the `\noexpand` topic in detail, but for the future I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @ChristianDomes Happy to help!  And I was just amused by the coincidence, and that I had completely forgotten that answer until I tried to save your code with that particular filename.  Even if you hadn't seen it, it was very useful to me in figuring out what the issue might be - it led me straight to it.

Comment: @ Andrew Stacey Since this is somehow related to my aforementioned topic, I would like to ask you, if it is also possible to add nodes at each line in the loop with `\noexpand \node[right, \footnotesize]  at (B1-\i) {$\mathrm{\nu_{\i}}$};`? If you have an idea I would be thankful, otherwise I will post a new question.

Comment: @Excelsior You'd probably need to add some more `\noexpand`s in front of the `\footnotesize` and `\mathrm` and `\nu`.  Another option would be to define a `pic` with all the various drawing commands in it which took a couple of arguments (probably in place of `\i` and `\n`) and then use the `.expand once` handler to just expand the `\i` and `\n` prior to feeding them to the `pic`.